# "Conda remove <package>" taking forever to remove package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I notice if I am trying to remove huge conda packages that occupy hundreds of megabytes in space, running `conda remove <package>` will take forever. Some examples of these huge packages are `pystan`, `spacy-model-en_core_web_lg`.

It is stuck at with no error messages;

> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

> Solving environment:

Any hints how to fix this problem?

I am using anaconda, python 3.8, windows 10.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Conda's remove operation still needs to satisfy all the other specifications for the environment, so Conda invokes its solver and this can be complicated. Essentially, it re-solves the entire environment *sans* the specified package, compares that against the existing state, then makes a plan based on the difference.

I very much doubt there is anything directly impactful about size of package, which OP alludes to. Instead, things that negatively impact solving are:

- having a large environment (e.g., `anaconda` package is installed)
- channel mixing - in particular, including the **conda-forge** channel at equal or higher priority as **defaults** in an environment with the `anaconda` package; that package and all its dependencies are intended to be sourced from the **anaconda** channel
- having an underspecified environment (see `conda env export --from-history` to see your explicit specifications); e.g., an environment with a `python=3.8` specification will be easier on the solver than just a `python` specification

In general, using smaller specialized (e.g., per-project) environments, rather than large monolithic ones helps avoid such problems. The `anaconda` package is particularly problematic.

#### Try Mamba

Other than adopting better practices, one can also get significantly faster solves with [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#readme), a drop-in compiled replacement for `conda`. Try it out:

```bash
## install Mamba in base env
conda install -n base conda-forge::mamba

## use it like you would the 'conda' command
mamba remove -n foo bar
```

Comment: `mamba` works very well. It fixed my problems. Thank you very much.