# Halting "conda remove" command in Miniconda3

Tags: linux, conda, miniconda, kill-process, mobaxterm

**Background:** I'm working on a research project on a High-Performance Computing machine running Linux OS that requires a fair amount of setup to log into. I use [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) and a VPN; it takes a while to get everything logged in for a working terminal session.

I'm using [Miniconda3](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) for managing my environments, but one environment specifically has gotten quite large and removing packages is taking hours upon hours.

**Problem:** The command `$ conda remove [package name]` takes forever to run and I'm currently browsing solutions for it. I would like to not have to restart my terminal every time I run the conda command as it gets stuck running indefinitely for my large environment.

This image is the line at which the remove command gets stuck.
[Linux terminal snippet of conda remove command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxIVw.png)

**Question:** Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut/solution for Linux using a Dell Laptop for halting/killing conda commands?

**What I've Tried:**
I've been trying the following key combinations:
Esc |  Ctrl + Q | Ctrl + Shift + Q ... and similar combinations of Ctrl, Shift, Q, Esc

I've looked for ways MobaXTerm can stop the command and have checked various "Terminal" options, etc.

I've reviewed [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193016/all-conda-command-either-get-killed-by-zsh-or-no-output), [this page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html), [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186607/conda-remove-package-extremely-slow-not-working-at-all) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983500/conda-remove-package-taking-forever-to-remove-package?newreg=4f09a82df6764c6e9b19e23f76213027) to find something... but all of my searches with relevant keywords haven't turned up anything yet.

*If anyone knows the secret to simply killing this command (and maybe other slow conda commands) without restarting my whole session, it would speed up my progress and make my life much easier. Thank you in advance!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my own question!

**Ctrl-C** in the terminal will send a SIGINT (signal interrupt) that terminates the current running process for any process I assume, not just miniconda.

I found more information on this site: [How to kill a process on Linux](https://linuxhint.com/kill_process_linux-2/)